# openByDefault attribute not working properly for Drawer.Navigator conditionally ("@react-navigation/drawer": "^5.12.5")

Tags: react-native, react-navigation-v5

I'm using Drawer.Navigator to create a toggle menu in react native, want to open/close drawer based on some conditions. It is not working as excepted.

```
<Drawer.Navigator
  drawerContentOptions={{
    activeTintColor: "#e91e63",
    itemStyle: { marginVertical: 5 },
  }}
  drawerContent={(props) => <CustomDrawerContent {...props} />}
  initialRouteName="Home"
  openByDefault={storedCredentials.isDrawerOpen}
>
```

when I console the storedCredentials.isDrawerOpen, it is giving true or false as expected but it's not opening/closing the drawer.
Help will be appreciated.

**UPDATE**

```
    const DrawerRoutes = ({ navigation }) => {
  const { storedCredentials, setStoredCredentials } =
    useContext(CredentialsContext);

  useLayoutEffect(() => {
    storedCredentials.data &&
    storedCredentials.data.flats &&
    storedCredentials.data.flats.length === 1
      ? setStoredCredentials(
          {
            ...storedCredentials,
            flat: storedCredentials.data.flats[0],
            isDrawerOpen: false,
          }
        )
      : setStoredCredentials(
          {
            ...storedCredentials,
            isDrawerOpen: true,
          }
        );
    console.log(storedCredentials);
  }, []);
```

This is where I'm setting the context, and then using it in openByDefault attribute.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`openByDefault` cannot be changed dynamically.

If you want to open/close the drawer manually, dispatch the relevant action.

https://reactnavigation.org/docs/drawer-actions/

Comment: Thanks, I kind of already figured that out, but yes this worked, instead of openByDefult i need to use navigation.dispatch action.

Answer (score 0):

You might missing parentheses `()` after storedCredentials.isDrawerOpen
use it like this `storedCredentials.isDrawerOpen()`

Comment: storedCredentials.isDrawerOpen is an object, not a method/function, which I'm getting from context. I have updated my question.